# Read specific column from .mat file in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-load

I want to load specific column form .mat file already exist in the work space after I load it how should I write then ?

Comment: Yes exactly that is my problem .. Thus, I should load all variables then access a specific one

Answer (score 3):

You can access part of a variable saved in a MAT file using [MATFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/matfile.html) constructor (available since R2011b). Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9135329/163080) to another similar question.

For example, if you have matrix `a` saved in `matlab.mat` file you constract the matfile object as

```
matObj = matfile('matlab.mat');
```

Then you can access 2nd column like `x = matObj.a(:,2);`.