# Need help discovering the contents of a VERY large .mat file

Tags: matlab, import, matrix

I have a .mat file which is too big (2.72 GB) to load. Is there any way I could know the contents of the file without opening? I need to know the name of matrices inside the .mat file to  use in the code.

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
>> whos('-file','yourfilename.mat')
```

Comment: Thanks. Now when I run my code I am getting the error :-           Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.                    Is there any way to fix this? It is happening because of loading the 2.72 GB .mat file.

Comment: I have never had memory issues, but [this thread appears to offer solutions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134032/how-can-i-load-large-files-150mb-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

The 'whos' function will list the variables in a mat file for you.

```
whos('-file','matFile.mat')
```